# Revenue in Admob drops drasticly. Is there an issue?

Tags: android, admob

Anybody knows of any issues regarding admob these days?
Because i have seen a drastic drop. while my users in Google Analytics are quite the same as before.

[image]

Comment: This is not programming related question

Comment: admob is moving to a new platform and the old platform will be shutdown. find the new platform here https://apps.admob.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ad revenue.

Comment: FWIW, I see the same issue. It happened before and after a day or 2 the numbers went back to normal